# Unknown Errors when trying to select category

Tags: error

Just like the post says, I'm getting unknown errors when selecting a category from a field. Nothing shows up in the craft error logs but here's what the console says:

[image: error]

Just wondering if anyone else experienced this or if it's just a problem with our build.

Comment: Looks like we're getting a 500 error with the modal trying to load this page: /index.php?p=admin/actions/elements/get-modal-body

Comment: If you check the Craft `storage/logs` folder, the underlying 500 ISE error message should be there.

Comment: @BradBell I cleared the error logs and tried again. Only thing I got was a warning that it couldn't find the retour icon:  2019-02-14 09:47:42 [-][1][-][warning][craft\controllers\DashboardController::_getWidgetIconSvg] Widget icon file doesn't exist: /home/234685.cloudwaysapps.com/genxabcuuj/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-retour/src/assetbundles/retour/dist/img/icon-mask.svg

Comment: It's giving me the same console error: there's a notification that say "Double-instantiating a menu button on an element" and then "failed to load resource" with that same element – Matthew Rotter 15 mins ago    Delete

Comment: @BradBell any idea on this? We think it could be server related because it happens more frequently on some environments but it's difficult to find a pattern

Comment: Looks like it was a server issue with something in our htaccess file. We checked the server errors logs and found it

Comment: Glad you got it sorted... would you mind adding it as an official answer? Might end up helping someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the server didn't like the .htaccess file we use for Craft 2 - specifically this part:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
   AddCharset utf-8 .atom \
                    .bbaw \
                    .css \
                    .geojson \
                    .ics \
                    .js \
                    .json \
                    .jsonld \
                    .manifest \
                    .markdown \
                    .md \
                    .mjs \
                    .rdf \
                    .rss \
                    .topojson \
                    .webapp \
                    .webmanifest \
                    .xloc \
                    .xml
</IfModule>
```

There weren't any errors in Craft but the PHP logs did have some information that helped us track this down.